# NOT NULL constraint failed: teams_team.user_id

Tags: python, django

When I submit a new team as a authenticated user, I get this error is showing. I searched a lot of answers but they say do it `null=True` or `default=1` but I don't want to be it null or something I want to be user's id it. Plus I imported and tried **settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL** and **get_user_model**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


#models.py
class Team(models.Model):
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='teams', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    rank = models.IntegerField(default=0)

#views.py
class TeamsCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamCreationForm

#forms.py
class TeamCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('name',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the `form_valid` method, and set `user` on the form's instance before saving it.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class TeamsCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.CreateView):
    model = Team
    form_class = TeamCreationForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.user = self.request.user
        return super(TeamsCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Use [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.mixins.LoginRequiredMixin) to make sure that users can only access the view if they are logged in.

Comment: from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

Comment: Thank you! It worked. But can i ask you one more question?